# How i can pass the icon in this compossable function ? So that i can reuse it

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

@Composable
fun LoginMethod(icon: Icon , text : String) {

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(8.dp)
        .shadow(
            elevation = 6.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp)
        )
) {
    Image(imageVector = icon , contentDescription ="")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
    Text(text = text)

}
```

}

Comment: I don't understand. You CAN use the passed icon anywhere inside the Composable as far as I know

Comment: If you wish to reuse the icon passed at a specific place in your code, and reuse it somewhere else by referencing the Composable, jetpack compose does not work that way. You cannot reference the Composables like views

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
@Composable 
fun LoginMethod(icon: ImageVector, text : String) {

  /* your code */
}
```

and then call it with:

```
LoginMethod(  Icons.Filled.Add, "title" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to access the icon anywhere, store it in a viewmodel. You cannot re-reference the Composable from anywhere like views, but as far as the usage INSIDE the scope of the Composable is concerned, you can use the passed-in icon anywhere inside it. You must store it for use outside